# Error: Unable to access jar file spring-restful-api.jar when executing docker run

Tags: java, spring, docker, maven, intellij-idea

### DOCKERFILE

```
FROM openjdk:14 <br>
RUN mkdir rest-api <br>
ADD spring-restful-api.jar rest-api/spring-restful-api.jar <br>
WORKDIR rest-api <br>
RUN pwd <br>
EXPOSE port_number <br>
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/res-api/spring-resful-api.jar"]
```

---

The image builds successfully in docker without any errors, when i execute `docker run -p port_number:port_number image_name`
I get this error:

```
Error: Unable to access jar file spring-restful-api.jar
```

A friend of mine did the same steps as me and his .jar doesn't make a problem 
I sent him my .jar and it says `Error: Unable to access jarfile spring-restful-api.jar` to him too. 
Using Intellij Ultimate JDK 14

Comment: could it be because of a typo in ENTRYPOINT? res-api

Comment: Thank you so much, im ashamed of myself for missing such a thing.
it works now!.